# Finding multiple regex hits using approximate matching via the tre library

Tags: c, regex, approximate, tre-library

Using C, I'm trying to find the location and number of matches of a substring within another parent string.  Because I also need to include approximate (hamming distance) matches, I'm using the tre library found here: http://laurikari.net/tre/.

I'm having trouble understanding some of the documentation on the site, likely because I'm not too familiar with regex lingo.  According to the tre documentation, I can get more specific information about 'submatches'.  Are these the matches I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: added a tre-library tag.  it doesn't seem to have many questions on SO...  but just in case anyone is looking.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a bit more about what you're trying to match. Some examples of the input string(s) and desired output would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To answer a part of your question about sub-matches: take the example string:

```
"noise aaa123bbb456ccc more noise"
```

and the regex:

```
aaa(.*?)bbb(.*?)ccc
```

then the entire match holds `aaa123bbb456ccc` which has two sub-matches in it: `123` and `456`. These sub-matches are also called groups (the strings that are matched by the part of the regex between parenthesis).